# WebGL: INVALID_VALUE: texImage2D: no video error in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, video, webgl

I'm attempting to add video as texture in WebGL. The project is simple and only involves one object. The code I have works fine in Firefox but claims there is no video when loaded in Chrome. The ERROR seems to be that the video is not starting in Chrome for some reason even though I have a function to start the video:

```
function startVideo() {
  videoElement.play();
  intervalID = setInterval(draw, 15);
}
```

as well as

```
videoElement.preload = "auto";
```

tied to my video objectin JS.

Additionally, I also have

```
<video id="video" src="Firefox.ogv" autoplay muted>
      Your browser doesn't appear to support the <code>&lt;video&gt;</code> element.
</video>
```

just to be sure, but it is not loadng the texture. The error is being referenced in this function for teximage2D:

```
function updateTexture() {
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, modelTexture);
  gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true);
  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, videoElement);
}
```

Subsequently, I also get the error:

```
RENDER WARNING: texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. It maybe non-power-of-2 and have incompatible texture filtering.
```

I am using this tutorial combined with my own implemenation :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API/Tutorial/Animating_textures_in_WebGL

My JS and HTML are located here:

https://github.com/TacoB0t/CSC43/tree/prog/prog5

Everything mostly takes place in the init() and draw() function of the JS

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="webgl-utils.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="webgl-debug.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="cuon-utils.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="cuon-matrix.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="prog5.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="chest.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="cube.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body onload="init()">
            <script id="vertexShader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
                    precision mediump float;

                    uniform mat4 modelMatrix;
                    uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
                    uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
                    uniform vec4 lightPosition;

                    attribute vec4 vertexPosition;  
                    attribute vec3 vertexNormal;
                    attribute vec2 vertexTexCoord;                              

                    varying vec3 fragmentNormal;
                    varying vec3 fragmentLight;
                    varying vec3 fragmentView;
                    varying vec4 fragmentPosition; 
                    varying vec2 fragmentTexCoord;                              

                    void main() {
                            mat4 modelViewMatrix = viewMatrix * modelMatrix;

                            vec4 p = modelViewMatrix * vertexPosition;
                            vec4 q = viewMatrix * lightPosition;                            

                            fragmentPosition    = vertexPosition; 
                            fragmentNormal      = normalize(mat3(modelViewMatrix) * vertexNormal);
                            fragmentLight       = normalize(vec3(q - p));
                            fragmentView        = normalize(vec3(-p));
                            fragmentTexCoord    = vertexTexCoord;               

                            gl_Position     = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vertexPosition;
                    }
            </script>
            <script id="lightingFragmentShader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
                    precision mediump float;

                    varying vec3 fragmentNormal;
                    varying vec3 fragmentLight;
                    varying vec3 fragmentView;
                    varying vec4 fragmentPosition; 
                    varying vec2 fragmentTexCoord;

                    uniform sampler2D modelTexture;
                    uniform vec3 modelColor;
                    uniform vec3 lightColor;

                    void main() {
                            vec3 n = normalize(fragmentNormal);
                            vec3 l = normalize(fragmentLight);
                            vec3 v = normalize(fragmentView);
                            vec3 h = normalize(l + v);
                            vec4 modelColor          = texture2D(modelTexture, fragmentTexCoord);

                            float d = max(dot(l,n) , 0.0);
                            float s = pow(max(dot(h, n), 0.0), 10.0);

                            vec3 fragmentColor  = vec3(modelColor) * lightColor * d + lightColor * s;

                            gl_FragColor        = vec4(fragmentColor, 1.0); 
                    }
            </script> 
            <center>
                <canvas id="webgl" width="500px" height="500px">
                    This content requires <a href="http://get.webgl.org/">WebGL</a>
                </canvas>
                <font face ="Arial">
                    <br>
                    Light Source Position
                    <br>
                    X-AXIS<input id="x-light" type="range" min="-5.0" max="5.0" value="0" step="0.1" oninput="refresh()">
                    <br>
                    Y-AXIS <input id="y-light" type="range" min="-5.0" max="5.0" value="0" step="0.1" oninput="refresh()">
                    <br>
                    Z-AXIS<input id="z-light" type="range" min="-5.0" max="5.0" value="0" step="0.1" oninput="refresh()">
                </font>
            </center>
        <video id="video" src="Firefox.ogv" autoplay muted style="display: none;">
       Your browser doesn't appear to support the <code>&lt;video&gt;</code> element.
         </video>
    </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
var gl;
var canvas;

var dragging = false;
var texShader;
var chestModel;

var xValue = 0;
var yValue = 0;
var zValue = 0;

var modelRotationX = 0;
var modelRotationY = 0;
var lastClientX;
var lastClientY;

var videoElement;
var modelTexture;
var copyVideo;

//refresh function used to request animation frame after moving slider in HTML
function refresh(){
    xValue = document.getElementById("x-light").value;
    yValue = document.getElementById("y-light").value;
    zValue = document.getElementById("z-light").value;
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

//define 'flatten' function to flatten tables to single array
function flatten(a) {    
    return a.reduce(function (b, v) { b.push.apply(b, v); return b }, [])   
}

//create tumble interaction functions to click and drag cube
function onmousedown(event){
    dragging    = true;
    lastClientX = event.clientX;
    lastClientY = event.clientY;
}

function onmouseup(event){ 
    dragging = false;
}

/*using clientX and clientY derived from click event, use to create modelX and Y 
rotation before passing to model matrices rotation transformations*/
function onmousemove(event){
    //console.log(event.clientX, event.clientY);
    if (dragging){  
        var dX = event.clientX - lastClientX;
        var dY = event.clientY - lastClientY;

        modelRotationY = modelRotationY + dX;
        modelRotationX = modelRotationX + dY;


        if (modelRotationX > 90.0){
            modelRotationX = 90.0;
        }

        if (modelRotationX < -90.0){
            modelRotationX = -90.0;
        }

    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    }
     lastClientX = event.clientX;
     lastClientY = event.clientY;

}
function startVideo() {
  videoElement.play();
  intervalID = setInterval(draw, 15);
}

function videoDone() {
  clearInterval(intervalID);
}


//define Shader object constructor function
function Shader(vertexId, fragmentId){

    this.program = createProgram(gl, document.getElementById( vertexId).text,
                                     document.getElementById(fragmentId).text);

    this.modelMatrixLocation         = gl.getUniformLocation(this.program, 'modelMatrix');
    this.viewMatrixLocation          = gl.getUniformLocation(this.program, 'viewMatrix');
    this.projectionMatrixLocation    = gl.getUniformLocation(this.program, 'projectionMatrix');
    this.vertexPositionLocation      = gl.getAttribLocation(this.program, 'vertexPosition'); 
    this.lightPositionLocation       = gl.getUniformLocation(this.program, 'lightPosition');
    this.modelColorLocation          = gl.getUniformLocation(this.program, 'modelColor');
    this.lightColorLocation          = gl.getUniformLocation(this.program, 'lightColor');
    this.vertexNormalLocation        = gl.getAttribLocation(this.program, 'vertexNormal');
    this.vertexTexCoordLocation      = gl.getAttribLocation(this.program, 'vertexTexCoord');

    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(this.vertexPositionLocation);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(this.vertexNormalLocation);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(this.vertexTexCoordLocation);
}

//define use() method for Shader objects
Shader.prototype.use = function(projectionMatrix, modelMatrix, viewMatrix){

    gl.useProgram(this.program);

    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(this.modelMatrixLocation, false, modelMatrix.elements);
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(this.viewMatrixLocation, false, viewMatrix.elements);
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(this.projectionMatrixLocation, false, projectionMatrix.elements);

    gl.uniform4f(this.lightPositionLocation, xValue, yValue, zValue, 0.0);
    gl.uniform3f(this.modelColorLocation, 0.6, 0.3, 0.2);
    gl.uniform3f(this.lightColorLocation, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
}

//define Model object constructor function
function Model(positions, triangles, normals, texCoords){
    //initialize buffer objects
    this.positionBuffer  = gl.createBuffer();
    this.triangleBuffer  = gl.createBuffer();
    this.normalsBuffer   = gl.createBuffer();
    this.texCoordBuffer  = gl.createBuffer();


    //copy vertex data from array in CPU onto GPU
    this.positionArray = new Float32Array(flatten(positions));
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.positionBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.positionArray, gl.STATIC_DRAW);    

    //copy triangle data from array in CPU onto GPU
    this.triangleArray = new Uint16Array(flatten(triangles));
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.triangleBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.triangleArray, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    this.normalsArray = new Float32Array(flatten(normals));
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.normalsBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.normalsArray, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    this.textCoordArray = new Float32Array(flatten(texCoords));
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.texCoordBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.textCoordArray, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
}

//define draw() method for Model objects to bind barray buffers
Model.prototype.draw = function(shader){

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.positionBuffer);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(shader.vertexPositionLocation, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.normalsBuffer);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(shader.vertexNormalLocation, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.texCoordBuffer);    
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(shader.vertexTexCoordLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);


    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.triangleBuffer);
    gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, this.triangleArray.length, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);


}

//initizlize texture object
function loadTexture(image, texture){
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    //requestAnimationFrame(draw);                                                        
}


function init(){

    //initialize GL context
    canvas = document.getElementById('webgl');
    gl = getWebGLContext(canvas, false);

    canvas.onmousedown  = onmousedown;
    canvas.onmouseup    = onmouseup;
    canvas.onmousemove  = onmousemove;

    //instantiate shader objects for each defined shader
    texShader           = new Shader('vertexShader', 'lightingFragmentShader');

    //instantiate model objects for each model
    chestModel          = new Model(chest.positions, chest.triangles, chest.normals, chest.texCoords);

    videoElement = document.getElementById("video");

    modelTexture    = gl.createTexture();

    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, modelTexture);
    gl.texImage2D(
        gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 1, 1, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,
        new Uint8Array([255, 255, 255, 255]));


    videoElement.addEventListener("canplaythrough", startVideo, true);
    videoElement.addEventListener("playing", function (){ copyVideo = true; }, true);
    videoElement.addEventListener("ended", videoDone, true);

   /* videoElement.onload   = function() {
       loadTexture(videoElement, modelTexture);
    }*/ 
    loadTexture(videoElement, modelTexture);

    videoElement.crossOrigin  = "anonymous";
    videoElement.src = "Firefox.ogv";


    gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true);                               
    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

    //request animation frame
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);    

}


function draw(){
     if (copyVideo) {
       updateTexture();
    }
    //compose matrices for transformations
    var viewMatrix          = new Matrix4();
    var projectionMatrix    = new Matrix4();  

    viewMatrix.translate(0.0, 0.0, -1.8);
    projectionMatrix.perspective(90, 1, 1, 10);

    //set color and refresh rendering for canvas       
    gl.clearColor(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    /*instantiate model matrices for each respective model 
      and draw models with applied shader*/
    var chestModelMatrix    = new Matrix4();
    chestModelMatrix.rotate(modelRotationX, 1, 0, 0 );
    chestModelMatrix.rotate(modelRotationY, 0, 1, 0 ); 
    chestModelMatrix.translate(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 );

    //set uniform locations and apply shader to designated model
    texShader.use(projectionMatrix, chestModelMatrix, viewMatrix);    
    chestModel.draw(texShader);

}

function updateTexture() {
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, modelTexture);
  gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true);
  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, videoElement);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an HTML video expert but this works for me. You need to wait for the `playing` event before you start copying the video to a texture

```
var copyVideo;    // if true we can call gl.texImage2D
var video = document.createElement("video");
video.src = someVideoUrl;

video.addEventListener("playing", function() {
  copyVideo = true;
}, true);
video.addEventListener("ended", function() {
  video.currentTime = 0;
  video.play();
}, true);

video.play();
```

Working example:

```js
"use strict";
var m4 = twgl.m4;
var gl = document.getElementById("c").getContext("webgl");
var programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, ["vs", "fs"]);

var bufferInfo = twgl.primitives.createCubeBufferInfo(gl, 2);

var camera = m4.identity();
var view = m4.identity();
var viewProjection = m4.identity();

var texture = twgl.createTexture(gl, {
  src: [0, 0, 255],
  format: gl.RGB,
  min: gl.LINEAR,
  wrap: gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE,
});

var uniforms = {
  u_texture: texture,
  u_worldViewProjection: m4.identity(),
};

var copyVideo;
var video = document.createElement("video");
video.src = "https://webglsamples.org/color-adjust/sample-video.mp4";
video.crossOrigin = "*";
video.volume = 0; // sample video has bad audio
video.addEventListener("playing", function() {
  copyVideo = true;
}, true);
video.addEventListener("ended", function() {
  video.currentTime = 0;
  video.play();
}, true);
video.addEventListener("error", function() {
  console.log("could not play video");
}, true);

video.play();

function render(time) {
  time *= 0.001;
  twgl.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);
  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

  gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

  var radius = 5;
  var orbitSpeed = time;
  var projection = m4.perspective(30 * Math.PI / 180, gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight, 0.5, 100);
  var eye = [Math.cos(orbitSpeed) * radius, 3, Math.sin(orbitSpeed) * radius];
  var target = [0, 0, 0];
  var up = [0, 1, 0];

  if (copyVideo) {
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture)
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGB, gl.RGB, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, video);
  }

  m4.lookAt(eye, target, up, camera);
  m4.inverse(camera, view);
  m4.multiply(projection, view, viewProjection);

  m4.copy(viewProjection, uniforms.u_worldViewProjection);

  gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);
  twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, bufferInfo)
  twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, uniforms);
  twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, bufferInfo);

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
#c { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; display: block; }
```

```html
<script id="vs" type="notjs">
uniform mat4 u_worldViewProjection;

attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec2 texcoord;

varying vec2 v_texCoord;

void main() {
  v_texCoord = texcoord;
  gl_Position = u_worldViewProjection * position;
}
  </script>
  <script id="fs" type="notjs">
precision mediump float;

varying vec2 v_texCoord;
uniform sampler2D u_texture;

void main() {
  gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoord);
}
  </script>
  <script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/2.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately, it simply returns the error 'cannot play video'. So i'll try to use that to track down the issue in chrome

Comment: It appears that the video stops playing when I attempt to access it by way of video = document.getElementById("video");

Comment: After trying to move some things around, I now get a new error that says "DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found." However, it still works inFirefox.

Comment: So then what are you doing different from the example?

Comment: I upated my code to reflect changes I tried to implement from your source and your earlier suggestion. The video gets cancelled in network requests. It plays normally in its elemnt until its used in the JS. if video = document.getElementById('video'); is disabled, it loads fine in HTML. However, adding those listeners causes it to not work in firefox as well. There is audio in both browsers but no video

Comment: I have no idea what "video gets cancelled in network requests" means. A few issues with the code in the question. It calls `requestAnimationFrame` in 3 places so it's going to have 2 rendering loops. It doesn't init the texture with data before the video starts so it's going to get rendering errors until it does. you need to init with data or don't use it until the first time you copy the video to it.

Comment: [These changes](http://pastebin.com/YgZp9WT8) work for me in both Chrome and Firefox

Comment: Ok, the changes are a huge progress. It works in Firefox but now, in Chrome, it just draws a white chest with no errors at all this time. I implemented all the changes and only changed '() => { copyVideo = true; }'     to     'function ()  { copyVideo = true; }'.

Comment: I hate to ask this, but any chance you can post the full version of the version that is working for you? I updated my post to include what I am using with your changes implemented.